# Argument only used in unevaluated context within the body of a constexpr function

Tags: c++, c++14, constexpr

The following piece of code has successfully compiled with gcc 5.3.0 but has failed to compile with clang 3.7.0. I used the online coliru compilers with the same command line options in both cases: -std=c++14 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread.

```
#include <cstdio>

// Definition of constexpr function 'foo'.
constexpr std::size_t foo(const int& arg_foo) { return sizeof(arg_foo); }

// Definition of function 'test'.
void test(const int& arg)
{ 
  // The following line produces an error with clang.
  constexpr std::size_t res_foo = foo(arg);

  // Print the result returned by the 'foo' function.
  std::printf("res_foo = %lu\n", res_foo);
}

// Definition of function 'main'.
int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
  // Test function call.
  test(argc);

  // Return statement.
  return 0;
}
```

clang rejects it with the following error:

```
error: constexpr variable 'res_foo' must be initialized by a constant expression
constexpr size_t res_foo = foo(arg);
                           ~~~~^~~~
```

Because of this difference between the two compilers, I am wondering if this is a valid piece of code. If not, I would like to get a better understanding of why this is the case.

Comment: gcc bug, one of many when it comes to constexpr

Comment: @TemplateRex But in what way does `foo` break any of the rules of a constexpr function?

Comment: @Archimaredes no be, the error is that `arg`  in `test` is not `constexpr`

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing `const` and `constexpr` values together. The definition of [constexpr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr) is a value known at compile time. But the `argc`variable is only known at run time (it is a number of arguments passed to your executable). So you cannot assign it to another `constexpr` variable - `res_foo`. It is  Removing `constexpr` from the `res_foo` definition will make your code compilable.

The difference between `const` and `constexpr` can be simplified to something like this:
`const` - I'm not going to change this value
`constexpr` - This value is known at compile time *and* I'm not going to change it

My guess is that GCC is able to compile this code with O2 since you are not using the `arg_foo` argument and the size of it is known at the compile time. But it is still syntactically incorrect - compiler should emit an error, since non-constexpr value is assigned to a constexpr variable.

Comment: I think he's aware of this, his question is because he never actually uses the value of `argc`, he just takes `sizeof`, which is a constant expression.

Comment: @TartanLlama what's why gcc is able to compile this code with O2: it ignores the argument since it is not used and gives back a well-known at compile time value. But it is still syntactically incorrect - compiler should emit an error since non-`constexpr` value is assigned to a `constexpr` variable.

Comment: I know it's still syntactically incorrect, but I think that's what you should be addressing in the answer.

Comment: @TartanLlama you are right. Addressed your comment in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The program is well-formed, since `foo(arg)` is a prvalue core constant expression as defined in C++14 5.20/2.  In particular, there is no lvalue-to-rvalue conversion during the evaluation, which would make it not a constant expression.

Comment: Not really. Evaluating that requires evaluating the *id-expression* `arg`, which runs afoul of [expr.const]/2.9: "A conditional-expression e is a core constant expression unless the evaluation of e, following the rules of the
abstract machine (1.9), would evaluate one of the following expressions:[...] an id-expression that refers to a variable or data member of reference type unless the reference has a preceding initialization and either — it is initialized with a constant expression or — it is a non-static data member of an object whose lifetime began within the evaluation of e".

Comment: 5/8 "An unevaluated operand is not evaluated."

Comment: Yes, it's not evaluated inside `foo`. But it's evaluated outside it for argument passing. The first step of evaluating `foo(arg)` is to evaluate `foo` and `arg`.